# Is saving thumbnail preview as base64 in the local DB a good idea?

Tags: react-native, image, performance

I'm new to RN and I want to create something similar to the phone's native photo app. I'm developing a grid preview of all of a user's photos in a Flatlist. We're talking tens of thousands of photos. I'm saving the user's photo information in a local DB and was wondering if saving the thumbnail as base64 to boost performance is a good idea or not. What would be the standard practice in this scenario?

Edit: I'm using Expo's `MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync()` with pagination, it's not very performant. If I only request a few dozen photos it loads fast but you need more loads as you scroll your photos, if I load many at once, I can scroll faster but I have wait longer for each load. I even tried a quick load with a second larger load to trick the user into a feel of smooth scrolling. Wouldn't storing the results in a local DB make things much faster?

Answer (score 0):

Data is currently stored locally, adding a local database here is i think useless and adds complexity to your architecture

If you're building a rich-content app and get picture from the net, you can opt for cache and thumbnail solution

After all depends on how you want to present your application, if a preview of the image is sufficient before loading the large format image.

For my part I would prefer the cache and the thumbnail only when information passes through the internet, in the case of local data I set up a progressive loading of the images by detecting the images of the area to be loaded otherwise no need to load the others .

Comment: Please see my new edit, as I explained I've tried the local and it wasn't very performant.

Comment: Have you a expo snack or something to show me what you do please

https://snack.expo.dev/